# How to read json with an array of objects

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm trying to read a json coming from backend (C#).But I get TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
resp.Result[0].EMP_CODE
resp.content.[Result][0].EMP_CODE
```

The data looks like this

```
content: "{"Result":[{
"EMP_CODE":10724242,
"EMP_NAME":"Jack",
"NAT_CODE":"1",
"DEPT_CODE":"35",
"MOBILE_NO":"571454582"}],
"successFlg":1,"errMsg":null}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: usually the json content is in data. Try doing `resp.data.Result[0]`

Comment: I have tried that already. I get the same error @anny123

Comment: 1. post how you are making a request. also try to log response.data and see the results/post it here 2. Make a request from `postman` and see if you are getting response

Comment: Api is good and I get data, also how I post is also ok it's just reading the data is making the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) to deserialize JSON.

First you can make some classes to map the JSON:

```
public class Results
{
    [JsonProperty("Result")]
    public List<Employee> Result { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("successFlg")]
    public long SuccessFlag { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errMsg")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [JsonProperty("EMP_CODE")]
    public long EmpCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EMP_NAME")]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NAT_CODE")]
    public long NatCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DEPT_CODE")]
    public long DeptCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MOBILE_NO")]
    public long MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then you deserialize with [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// Other code

var json = @"{ ""Result"":[{
               ""EMP_CODE"":10724242,
               ""EMP_NAME"":""Jack"",
               ""NAT_CODE"":""1"",
               ""DEPT_CODE"":""35"",
               ""MOBILE_NO"":""571454582""}],
               ""successFlg"":1,""errMsg"":null}";

var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(json);
```

And fetch your content:

```
Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson.Result[0].EmpCode);
// 10724242
```